# Ruby Hash Methods difference :[] VS :dig

Tags: ruby

I use Ruby 2.3 and it has methods for Hash `dig`. So, before v2.3 If I had big hash with deep nesting, I should use many methods `[]`. Example

```
hashy = { a: { b: { c: { d: 1 }}}}
d_val = hashy[:a][:b][:c][:d] # => 1
```

in this case, each method's call allocate new memory place, because it's same as

```
a_val = hashy[:a] # => { b: { c: { d: 1 }}}
b_val = a_val[:b] # => { c: { d: 1 }}
c_val = b_val[:c] # => { d: 1 }
d_val = c_val[:d] # => 1
```

but what about `dig` from Ruby 2.3.

```
hashy.dig(:a, :b, :c, :d) # => 1
```

The method has written on C. So maybe it run in another way, without allocating additional (not necessary) memory?

Which is method preferable for use?

Comment: JFYI, both these methods are implemented in C.

Comment: Ahem … https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb#L534-L541 https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb#L394-L403

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>  d_val = hashy[:a][:b][:c][:d]
> ```
>
> in this case, each method's call allocate new memory place

False. Have you looked at the implementation of the method? There's no allocation there.

In that method, a new *reference* is created, which points to an existing hash object in memory. The hash object itself isn't copied, hence no "allocations".

> What is the difference between `[]` and `dig`?

The main difference is that `dig` is much more forgiving to nils in the middle of the chain. Allocation-wise, they appear to be similar (judging from the code).

Comment: but it is just chain of methods

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: So? Memory isn't copied. Just new references to the same objects are created.

Comment: Yes, but if calls chain of methods than each method allocate new memory

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: ah, for the stack? I wouldn't worry about those allocations.

Comment: yep, but maybe `dig` method solves this issue. Or it runs in the same way?

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: 1) it is not a real issue. 2) looking at the code, `dig` appears to have _more_ function calls (and this is no wonder, it does more work).